# Link to Google service API jar file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a SQLite database on Google Drive, but I am not able to download the right jar to perform the Uploading. I sow a lot of Example on how to upload the DB but I do not find the right JAR to include to the Android studio project.

I'd be most grateful if someone can add the link to download the JAR or JARs to include in the project.